# Realizar uma query verificando se esse registro já existe em outra tabela

Tags: mysql, sql

A lógica é a seguinte, eu tenho uma tabela "TBL_NOTICIAS" e outra tabela com nome "TBL_DESBLOQUEADO".

Quando o usuário acessa a página eu apresento todas as notícias e ele pode desbloquear a notícia que deseja para ler, e quando ele desbloqueia eu faço um registro na tabela "TBL_DESBLOQUEADO" com o id do cliente e id da notícia para que quando ele acessar a página novamente, as noticias que ele já desbloqueou não apareça.

Minha query precisaria ser tipo isso:
SELECT * FROM tbl_noticias WHERE ... (quando não existir na tbl_desbloqueado)

Lógica das tabelas:

TBL_NOTICIAS

- id
- titulo
- noticia

TBL_DESBLOQUEADO

- id
- id_cliente
- id_noticia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar o `NOT EXISTS` para a subquery, assim:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tbl_noticias 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_desbloqueado
                    WHERE id_cliente = 123 -- id do cliente
                      AND id_noticia = tbl_noticias.id)
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito Obrigado!